# Increment the ID attribute inside input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table inside a table where checkbuttons are attached with every field. There are three levels
1). Select All info
2). Parent
3). Child

What i want to do is that if i select "Select All Info" check button, it selects all the check boxes which is working fine. What i can't able to do is that if i select a "Parent" check box, it should select all the child's check boxes. I am trying to increment the Child_id field but didn't get any fruitful results.

Below is the code I am trying, any help or guidance would be useful

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

<script>
  $(function select(){
      $("#Select_All").change(function () {
          $("#Parent_Id, #Child_Id").prop("checked", this.checked);
           });
 
$("#Parent_Id").change(function(){ 
        var i=0;   
        $('#Child_Id').each(function(){
        i++;
        var newID='Child_Id'+i;
        $(this).attr('id', newID);
        $(this).val(i);
             $(newID).prop("checked", this.checked);
 });});});
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="10">
    <input type="checkbox" id = "Select_All" name="Main"  />Select All Information
<TD>
     <input type="checkbox" id = "Parent_Id" name="PPP" class = "Parent_Class" />parent

<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3">
       
<div>
  <TD>
 <input type="checkbox" id = "Child_Id" name="CCC" class = "Child_Class" /> Child1 </TD>     

 <TD>  
 <input type="checkbox" id = "Child_Id" name="CCC" class = "Child_Class" />Child2</TD> 
 <TR>
 <TD> 
<input type="checkbox" id = "Child_Id" name="CCC" class = "Child_Class" /> Child3</TD>  
<TD>  <input type="checkbox" id = "Child_Id" name="CCC" class = "Child_Class" />Child4
 </TD>  
</TR>
 </div>
</TABLE>
</TD>
<TD>     <input type="checkbox" id = "Child_Id" name="CCC" class = "Child_Class" />
 A table inside a table.</TD>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Why not use Angular and [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/4-2) for that?

Comment: I am new and my Boss gave me this task to do it using Javascript and jquery, I tried different things as per my knowledge in this language but stuck. I have to do it this way first :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("#Select_All").change(function () {
 $("#Parent_Id, #Child_Id").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
$("#Parent_Id").change(function(){ 
    //var i=0;   
    var isParentChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.Child_Class').each(function(){
        //i++;
        //var newID='#Child_Id'+i;
            //console.log(newID);
        //$(this).attr('id', newID);
        //$(this).val(i);
        $(this).prop("checked",isParentChecked);
  });
});
```

Since you change the id of each child element, then you check/uncheck the top most parent (Select_All) there is only "parent" element will be affected, so I comment some of lines of code to make it run properly.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Ls8jqz/4/)

Comment: Yep, it works and works as required. But still I have one more thing to do but I will scratch my head first and will come back if it didn't work out. But you save my day ! Thanks alot.

Comment: if that helped, then you may want to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work